# Wordpress en Nginx

Tags: php, apache, nginx

he instalado wordpress en mi servidor con Nginx pero no me funciona correctamente.

Mi archivo .conf es el siguiente:

```
server {
 listen 80;

 server_name ejemplo.com
 root /var/www/blogAlexis;

 # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
 index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;



 location ~ ^/.well-known {
    allow all;
 }

 location / {
 # First attempt to serve request as file, then
 # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
 try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
 error_page 405 = $uri;
 }

 # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
 #
 location ~ \.php$ {
 include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

 fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
 }

 # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
 # concurs with nginx's one
 location ~ /\.ht {
  deny all;
 }
}
```

El problema que al intentar instalar un plugin me pide los datos para acceder por ftp y al introducirlo me devuelve error.

```
Fallo al conectar al servidor FTP 00.00.00.00:22
```

Yo lo relleno en SFTP pero nada. También me devuelve error al modificar una imagen, no se si tendrá más errores por que casi no lo  he probado. Puede ser que me falte alguna librería?? o algo he hecho mal??

Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo, a ver si puedo ayudarte, ya que al ser una situación que cuesta reproducir, creo que tu problema está en la configuración.

Una conexión ftp es delicada, ya que se trata de transferencia de archivos, una mala configuración podrías estar literalmente dejando abierto el servidor o no poder acceder. Ni tanto ni tan poco, en su justa medida ;)

Dicho esto, te propongo la posible configuración necesaria para permitir a tu servidor nginx aceptar conexiones ftp mediante tu aplicación de Wordpress

**1º** es crear un nuevo usuario.

```
sudo useradd -d /var/www/ ftpuser
```

Esto define ese directorio como directorio para el usuario ftp

**2º** sería crear una contraseña para este nuevo usuario

```
sudo passwd ftpuser
```

**3º**, paso importante. Agregar el "ftpuser" al grupo "www-data" que comunmente se utiliza y configura para gestionar nginx.

```
sudo usermod -aG www-data ftpuser
```

Ahora tu usuario ftp forma parte del grupo que maneja las comunicaciones de "nginx con el proyecto" y digamos nginx para ofrecer el servicio. De tal forma que ambos tienen las mismas capacidades, al igual que tu aplicación puede modificar archivos, este usuario también podrá hacerlo. Tantos permisos como conceda el grupo 'www-data'. Es importante tener claros algunos conceptos ya que la administración del sistema es algo delicado.

**4º** Ahora, hacer que el usuario tenga como grupo primario 'www-data', de tal forma que será su grupo por defecto, para evitar que se utilice otro en caso de reiniciar servicios.

```
sudo usermod -g www-data ftpuser
```

**5º** Ahora será necesario modificar el valor de usuario que se utilizará en el servidor nginx.

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

```
#Nginx configuration
user ftpuser;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
```

**6º** Verificar que la sintaxis de nginx es correcta.

```
sudo nginx -t
```

Deberías recibir algo similar a esto

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

**7º** Modificar usuario php-fpm

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

```
; Unix user/group of processes
; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
;       will be used.
user = ftpuser
group = www-data
```

**8º** Verificar sintaxis de php-fpm

```
sudo php-fpm7.0 -t
```

Deberías recibir algo similar a

```
NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful
```

En este punto, es necesario corregir los permisos modificados para php-fpm, ya que está configurado como ftpuser.

**9º** Modificar los permisos de las carpetas y directorios de home

```
sudo chown -R ftpuser:www-data /var/www
```

**10º** Permitir al usuario ftpuser y grupo www-data ejecutar estos directorios

```
sudo find /var/www/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} +
```

**11º** Permitir al usuario ftpuser y al grupo www-data escribir los archivos

```
sudo find /var/www/ -type f -exec chmod 664 {} +
```

**12º** Cambiar permisos de nginx y php en dierctorios

```
sudo chown -R ftpuser:www-data /var/lib/nginx
sudo chown -R ftpuser:www-data /var/log/nginx
sudo chown -R ftpuser:www-data /var/lib/php/sessions
```

**Hasta aquí sería todo con el tema de permisos**

---

**Neceistas ahora reiniciar los servicios**

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
sudo service nginx restart
```

Debería de funcionar todo correctamente. Si continuas con algún problema, prueba agregar estas lineas a tu **archivo de configuración** `wp-config.php`

```
// permission fixes
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
define( 'FS_CHMOD_DIR', ( 0775 & ~ umask() ) );
define( 'FS_CHMOD_FILE', ( 0664 & ~ umask() ) );
```

Para finalizar, te dejo este script para reiniciar los permisos de una tacada

```
USER=ftpuser
sudo chown -R ${USER}:www-data /var/www/
sudo find /var/www/ -type f -exec chmod 664 {} +
sudo find /var/www/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} +
sudo chown -R ${USER}:www-data /var/lib/nginx
sudo chown -R ${USER}:www-data /var/log/nginx
sudo chown -R ${USER}:www-data /var/lib/php/sessions
```

Espero que te ayude y puedas subir archivos pronto ;)

Saludos!

Comment: Brillante @Sergio. Muchas gracias por esa forma de elaborar tu respuesta y haciendo que entienda el fallo, a funcionado a la perfección :) Grande maestro!!!